# java - Line breaks not working

Tags: java, io

I'm writing a simple program that writes data to the selected file .
everything is going great except the line breaks `\n` the string is written in the file but without line breaks

I've tried `\n` and `\n\r` but nothing changed
the program :

```
    public void prepare(){
    String content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n\r<data>\n\r<user><username>root</username><password>root</password></user>\n\r</data>";
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found .. prepare()");
    }
    byte b[] = content.getBytes();
    try {
        fos.write(b);
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IOException .. prepare()");
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    File f = new File("D:\\test.xml");
    Database data = new Database(f);
    data.prepare();
}
```

Comment: What are you viewing the file in to see whether the line breaks appear?

Comment: Noticed you're writing to an XML File. The app you're opening up the xml file in is probably the culprit.

Comment: I'm viewing it on Notepad

Comment: Off topic:  Since you are working with XML, you should probably use the XML libraries (`javax.xml.*`).  Otherwise, you're likely to run into more formatting/encoding issues without any error support.

Answer (score 5):

Line endings for Windows follow the form `\r\n`, not `\n\r`.  However, you may want to use platform-dependent line endings.  To determine the standard line endings for the current platform, you can use:

```
System.lineSeparator()
```

...if you are running Java 7 or later.  On earlier versions, use:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

Comment: Beat me to it by an inch. :)

Comment: Keep in mind that using `System.lineSeparator()` will use the line endings for the current platform; which may not be appropriate for other platforms the file is viewed on. That's fine if the OP doesn't care. If you want to force a certain line separator regardless of what platform the application is running on, you still want to write them explicitly.

Comment: Hence "_may_ want to use" ;).

Comment: 1) That was directed at the OP. 2) We generally qualify our "may" in explanatory text, in the absence of mind reading. I did it for you, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're using Windows. Write `\r\n` instead of `\n\r` - as `\r\n` is the linebreak on Windows.

I'm sure you'll find that the characters you're writing into the file *are* there - but you need to understand that different platforms use different default line breaks... and different clients will handle things differently. (Notepad on Windows only understands `\r\n`, other text editors may be smarter.)

Answer (score 0):

The correct linebreak sequence on windows is `\r\n` not `\n\r`.

Also your viewer may interpret them differently. For example, notepad will only display CRLF linebreaks, but Write or Word have no problem displaying CR or LF alone.

You should use `System.lineSeparator()` if you want to find the linebreak sequence for the current platform. You are correct in writing them explicitly if you are attempting to force a linebreak format regardless of the current platform.